# Mapping same object type properties in a class invokes Equals and GetHashCode

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this class.

```
public class ConflictItem<T> where T : new()
    {
        public T CurrentItem { get; set; }
        public T RequestedUpdateItem { get; set; }
    }
```

Where T implements `bool Equals(object obj)`, `int GetHashCode()` and `IEquatable<SyncObject>`.

So let's say you have `IEnumerable<ConflictItem<Order>>` and map to `IEnumerable<ConflictItem<OrderDataObject>>`, this will invoke Equals and GetHashCode, which I don't understand the reason.

The problem is that the mapped result object `ConflictItem<OrderDataObject>` ends up with the same object instance in both CurrentItem and RequestedUpdateItem properties.

My simple Automapper configuration.

```
config.CreateMap<ConflictItem<Order>, ConflictItem<OrderDataObject>>().ReverseMap();
config.CreateMap<Order, OrderDataObject>().ReverseMap();
```

I understand when it comes to equality of objects in a list or between two objects but why Automapper will match equality for two different properties in another object? Is there any way to override this behavior with configuration?

Comment: Is this not just the underlying collections themselves?

Comment: I updated the question with the problem, I end up receiving a ConflictItem<OrderDataObject> with the same object instance in both properties.

Comment: How does invoking `Equals` cause those two properties to change?  I suspect you actually have a bad mapping configuration.  Can you show how you map and where you see that `Equals` is called?

Comment: I know is too strange, I can't explain it as well, but I validated with setting a breakpoint in my Equals overiden implementation in the class. Added the configuration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612176/automapper-not-mapping-correctly-when-same-type This is the same issue. Here maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333732/how-do-i-get-automapper-to-not-cache-mapped-objects Horrible behavior. The most voted solution also is really bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the library has added an option to disable caching as an option on the Map method:

```
var output = Mapper.Map<T1, T2>(input, opt => opt.DisableCache = true);
```

Try that and see if it resolves your issue.

I've been looking at the 5.0 Beta release on GitHub, and it seems they might be disabling this cache by default:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/releases/tag/v5.0.0-beta-1

Comment: It looks like that the default caching behavior is changed in latest Nuget package version. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1311